# Logic in approveAndCall function for erc20 token deprecated & not working

Tags: erc-20, calldata, erc-20-approve

I am following along with a older tutorial on making an ERC20 token in order to learn Solidity a little better.

Since the tutorial is old, I've had to change a lot of things so far to get it up to speed with version 0.8.0 (The version I am working with)

Now I am having an issue with function that is created to approve then call the receiving contract. Below is my code:

```
  /* Approves and then calls the receiving contract */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes memory _extraData) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

    //call the receiveApproval function on the contract you want to be notified. This crafts the function signature manually so one doesn't have to include a contract in here just for this.
    //receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _tokenContract, bytes _extraData)
    //it is assumed that when does this that the call *should* succeed, otherwise one would use vanilla approve instead.
    if(!_spender.call(abi.encode(bytes4(bytes32(keccak256("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)"))), msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData)))
    {
        revert(); 
        
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

The error I am getting is on the IF statement:

```
TypeError unary operator ! cannot be applied to type tuple(bool, bytes memory)
```

And

```
TypeError tuple(bool, bytes memory) is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool.
```

From my understanding call() is outdates and can be eliminated if I just simply use something else? However I am not sure what my other options are here.

If there are no other options, can someone please help me understand what I should be using this call() function for? And how I can implement a fix that would make sense?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From 0.5 the syntax for .call has changed. It accepts a single `bytes memory` parameter and returns a tuple `(bool, bytes memory)`.

That should be written as

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = _spender.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("receiveApproval(address,uint256,address,bytes)",
                                      msg.sender, _value, address(this), _extraData));
require(success, "Call failed");
```

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/050-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes